# Hyperlinks in my wordpress site are not working

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I have moved a wordpress site from one domain to another domain.

I have a problem now. All menus in my site are not working at all. 
These are simple `<a href="xyz">xyz</a>`. When I click on a link it does not redirect me to new URL, nothing happens.

http://syslotix.com/getarate/

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what does it actually do? When you hover over a link, where is it going to take you to? the old domain still?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the plugins and seeing if it works.

Comment: Also, you're getting loads of 404 not found errors on that website, one of which is a big JS file. Try fixing that first.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it by typing

```
http://syslotix.com/getarate/nj-mortgage-rates-new-jersey/
```

It works well. Then I looked into it

```
<a href="/getarate/nj-mortgage-rates-new-jersey/">NJ Mortgage Rates</a>
```

When we clicked this href, it also worked well. So it maybe not the link problem. Could be the problem of html or javascript or just your browser

Test it with other web browser or add `<div></div>` around `<a>your link</a>`. Let's see if it's the same result

If it still does not work. Check if your have copied all the .js files in your server. Sometimes we will forget them and just copy the html and css files

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is missing. You need to make sure that you replicated the file structure properly.